# Insert a row in the Sfdatagrid to say that there is no data

Tags: xamarin.forms, datagrid, syncfusion

I am inserting a syncfusion datagrid in my project, I populate it by making a call to a service, but it may happen that, with the various filters, the service responds without data, and therefore I wanted to insert (always as a grid row) a row that would indicate that there is no data, or otherwise a way to make sure that the header of the grid is always visible, because I think you know that in the absence of data, you don't even see the header.

Answer (score 0):

It may be easier to have a different view that appears when there is no data.

```xml
 <StackLayout>
    <Sfdatagrid x:Name="thedatagrid" ... IsVisible="True">
        ...
    </Sfdatagrid>
    <SomeOtherView x:Name="nodataview" ... IsVisible="False">
        ...
    </SomeOtherView>
</StackLayout>
```

In c# code behind:

```cs
// when no data
this.thedatagrid.IsVisible = false;
this.nodataview.IsVisible = true;

// when there is data
this.thedatagrid.IsVisible = true;
this.nodataview.IsVisible = false;
```

"nodataview" could be a different Sfdatagrid, that shows whatever you want.
OR it could be a different view entirely.